# screen display responsively position a Sprite with phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Is there a way to make the screen display responsively position a Sprite in the bottom right corner of the application, no matter what the game screen width may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set the origin of the Sprite to x=1,y=1 and position equal to game width and game height. Here is a pseudo code:

```
mySprite.setOrigin(1, 1);
mySprite.setX(this.sys.game.width);
mySprite.setY(this.sys.game.height);
```

Comment: Not working for me